# Wrong indentation Jinja template renders by Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I have an indentation problem with my YAML template.
I don't understand why `limits` is not at its correct indentation level.

Does someone have any idea?

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: argocd-notifications-controller
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: {% if argocd_total_applications > argocd.totalApplications.level4 -%} "{{ argocd.notificationController.cpu.requests.level4 }}"
              {% elif argocd_total_applications > argocd.totalApplications.level3 and argocd_total_applications <= argocd.totalApplications.level4 -%} "{{ argocd.notificationController.cpu.requests.level3 }}" 
              {% elif argocd_total_applications > argocd.totalApplications.level2 and argocd_total_applications <= argocd.totalApplications.level3 -%} "{{ argocd.notificationController.cpu.requests.level2 }}" 
              {% elif argocd_total_applications <= argocd.totalApplications.level1 -%} "{{ argocd.notificationController.cpu.requests.level1 }}" {% endif -%}
              memory: {% if argocd_total_applications > argocd.totalApplications.level4 -%} "{{ argocd.notificationController.memory.requests.level4 }}"
              {% elif argocd_total_applications > argocd.totalApplications.level3 and argocd_total_applications <= argocd.totalApplications.level4 -%} "{{ argocd.notificationController.memory.requests.level3 }}"
              {% elif argocd_total_applications > argocd.totalApplications.level2 and argocd_total_applications <= argocd.totalApplications.level3 -%} "{{ argocd.notificationController.memory.requests.level2 }}"
              {% elif argocd_total_applications <= argocd.totalApplications.level1 -%}"{{ argocd.notificationController.memory.requests.level1 }}"{% endif -%}
            limits:
              memory: {% if argocd_total_applications > argocd.totalApplications.level4 -%} "{{ argocd.notificationController.memory.limits.level4 }}" 
              {% elif argocd_total_applications > argocd.totalApplications.level3 and argocd_total_applications <= argocd.totalApplications.level4 -%} "{{ argocd.notificationController.memory.limits.level3 }}" 
              {% elif argocd_total_applications > argocd.totalApplications.level2 and argocd_total_applications <= argocd.totalApplications.level3 -%} "{{ argocd.notificationController.memory.limits.level2 }}" 
              {% elif argocd_total_applications <= argocd.totalApplications.level1 -%} "{{ argocd.notificationController.memory.limits.level1 }}" 
              {% endif -%}
```

Result:

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: argocd-notifications-controller
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "150m"
              memory: "500Mi"
              limits:  ################# PROBLEM HERE WRONG LOCATION
              memory: "750Mi"
```

Comment: Cannot say, but I have a recommendation that might help you fix the problem.  Compute all your values ahead of time with `{% set %}`, then print them in the proper format.

Comment: I was going to take a look, but I'm not inclined to figure out appropriate values for all your variables. Consider posting a sample set of data along with your template so that you an [mcve] that someone can run locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal reproducible example of your issue:

```
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: {% if true -%} "150m" 
    {% elif true -%} "" {% endif -%}
    memory: {% if true -%} "500Mi" 
    {% elif true -%} "" {% endif -%}
  limits:
    memory: {% if true -%} "750Mi" 
    {% elif true -%} "" {% endif -%}
```

Which renders, indeed, as:

```yaml
resources: 
  requests: 
    cpu: "150m"  
    memory: "500Mi"  
    limits: 
    memory: "750Mi"
```

Those incorrect missing indentation happens because you are removing the spaces with [whitespace control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#whitespace-control) after all your `endif`'s.

Remove the whitespace controls — or better, yet, fix them so they remove the correct whitespaces — and you will generate your expected YAML:

```
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: {% if true -%} "150m" 
    {%- elif true -%} "" {%- endif %}
    memory: {% if true -%} "500Mi" 
    {%- elif true -%} "" {%- endif %}
  limits:
    memory: {% if true -%} "750Mi" 
    {%- elif true -%} "" {%- endif %}
```

Will render as

```yaml
resources: 
  requests: 
    cpu: "150m" 
    memory: "500Mi" 
  limits: 
    memory: "750Mi"
```

Comment: Thanks you very much 
This issue helped me a lot too (#jinja2: trim_blocks: "true", lstrip_blocks: "false") : 
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10725#issuecomment-249494236